# Attach file to Outlook

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, outlook

I have the below code that I harvested from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268870.aspx). The code seems to have been originally used in an Add In and as such I am having a problem with the `this.Application.CreateItem(...)` portion.  What do I need to do differently to do this from my winform app?

```
private void AddAttachment(){

Outlook.MailItem mail =this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)as Outlook.MailItem;

mail.Subject = "An attachment for you!";

OpenFileDialog attachment = new OpenFileDialog();

attachment.Title = "Select a file to send";
attachment.ShowDialog();

if (attachment.FileName.Length > 0)
{
    mail.Attachments.Add(
        attachment.FileName,
        Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue,
        1,
        attachment.FileName);
    mail.Recipients.Add("Armando Pinto ");
    ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
}
```

Comment: I found the solution here, kinda. It doesn't really answer my question but it does work. [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SendFileToNET.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SendFileToNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're in a VSTO project so you get the Office References loaded.  If it's complaining up there, it's probably because it doesn't know what object you're trying to create.