# Send email with excel attachment from memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have created an action to export a table to excel in my mvc project using `officeopenxml`

Here is how I am converting my table to excel:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{
    _lstRecords = (List<Summary>) Session["Paging"];

    List<Excel> lstExportedExcel = new List<Excel>();

    foreach (var item in _lstRecords)
    {
        Excel export = new Excel();
        export.Date = item.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
        export.Assignment = item.codeAssignment.Assignment;
        export.County = item.codeCounty.County;

        lstExportedExcel.Add(export);
    }

    ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
    var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2c3e50");
    var border = ExcelBorderStyle.Double;
    var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    workSheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(lstExportedExcel.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList(), true);
    workSheet.DefaultColWidth = 25.0;
    workSheet.Cells[1,1,1,10].Style.Border.BorderAround(border, color);
    workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 10].Style.Font.Bold = true;
    workSheet.Cells.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
    workSheet.InsertRow(2,1);
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=SummaryRecords.xlsx");
        excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Now when the user clicks the button on the view.. they're taken to this action behind the scenes and a dialog comes up asking them to either open or save..

Now my next goal is to be able to add this excel sheet as an attachment to an email directly from my application.  So I want to add another button on my view that will open outlook with this excel sheet as an attachment, without them having to save the document.. is that possible, or does the user have to download the document?

Comment: Save the file at `Path.GetTempFileName()` and then attach the file to outlook as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715446/attach-file-to-outlook)